# Can you get a guest OS using PySphere?

Tags: python-2.7, vmware

I would like to find all the Linux machines on my VMServer.

I can run the following to get a list of all VMs.

```
vms = server.get_registered_vms()
mylist = []
for vm in vms:
    virtual_machine = server.get_vm_by_path(vm)
    mylist.append(virtual_machine.get_properties)
    print vm
```

But is there any way to grab the Guest OS that VMServer has. I.e I don't want a workaround that requires the machine to be on and needing to type lots of passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PySphere offers the methods [`get_properties` and `get_property(property_name)`](https://code.google.com/p/pysphere/wiki/GettingStarted#Getting_basic_properties:). If the property `guest_full_name` is set, you can find it here.

From the docs:

```
>>> vm1.get_properties()
{'guest_id': 'ubuntuGuest',
 'path': '[DataStore1] Ubuntu/Ubuntu-10.vmx',
 'guest_full_name': 'Ubuntu Linux (32-bit)',
 'name': 'Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop 2200',
 'mac_address': '00:50:56:aa:01:a7'
}
```

Therefore, to add to your script you could do:

```
vms = server.get_registered_vms()
mylist = []
for vm in vms:
    virtual_machine = server.get_vm_by_path(vm)
    guest_os = virtual_machine.get_property('guest_full_name')
    if server_guest_is_linux(guest_os):
        mylist.append(virtual_machine)
        print vm

def server_guest_is_linux(guest_os):
    if 'linux' in guest_os.lower() \
            or 'ubuntu' in guest_os.lower() \
            or 'centos' in guest_os.lower():
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Basically its just "virtual_machine.get_property('guest_full_name')"